# Permission denied when I try to open VSCode using a command line

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line, git-bash

I'm trying to edit a file by openning it via git using VS Code as an editor

```
$code texte.txt
```

and I got this

> /c/Users/MAYA/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code: line 61: /c/Users/MAYA/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe: Permission denied

I google it but didn' find anything usefull, any help please?

P.S: my environement: windows 7, MINGW64

Comment: git-bash ([details](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway)) has no knowledge of your host windows environment. Developing on windows, I've taken to learning PowerShell and using that terminal. If you especially like linux, I recommend looking into the [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).

Answer (score 1):

Thought it would be useful to share this as well.

> **WSL is not able to run VS Code with Windows environment administrator permissions.**

1. Right-click on your Visual Studio Code shortcut and select "Properties" in `C:\Users\<myUsername>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio Code`
2. In the Compatibility tab's settings section ***un-check*** "Run this program as an administrator"

A wonderful person brought this up on [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/jiau7k/cant_open_visual_studio_code_from_wsl_2_ubuntu/gp62nyz/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: This does not solve the problem of being unable to run the programmer as an administrator. In fact, it does the opposite---it actually causes you to run it as a standard user!

Comment: @spongyryno Thanks! Correct, it doesn't give you permissions in Windows directories. It looked like the person asking had their Linux command-line open. Unchecking it allows WSL users to run VS Code from WSL (and use admin permissions there instead).

Your comment does make me wonder if they were asking about the BASH emulator for windows though. A possible fix for that would be to go to where Git Bash is installed, right click on git-bash.exe, select properties, go to compatibility, and check "Run this program as an administrator".

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below and be proud of the OS you use.

1. Search for "Advanced System Setting" from Start.
2. Click on Environment Variables
3. On System Variables choose "path" from Variable tab and click on Edit.
4. Click on New on the right side of the popup window.
5. Copy your path from the Explorer's breadcrumb path and paste it into the
   new opened path in step 4, example:- C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS
   Code\bin
6. Click Ok on all the open windows to confirm changes and restart your  cmd
7. Now you run it  `$code.cmd file.extension`

Answer (score 0):

I added the path from the Explorer's breadcrumb to Environment Variables under Advanced System Setting then I used `$code.cmd file.extension`